# What are the options for a file cache for Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, .net-core, app-engine-flexible

I have a REST, .NET Core application running in Google App Engine Flexible.

It reads binary files from Cloud Storage (several MB in size, rarely hundreds of MB).
To make it running faster I'm caching these files in local file system (/tmp). But this approach doesn't work when the app is scaled and more instances are running simultaneously.

What are my options for fast file cache which is shared between app instances?

- Cloud Filestore looks great but is not available for App Engine
- Cloud Memorystore - I'm not sure it is suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [redis Database](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-redislabs-redis) to cache up to 30 mb of data for free from your App Engine and this is a solution easy to implement.

For this you only need to create a Redis Cloud database and modify the appsettings.json file of your app.